# How can we differentiate questions about a language from language libraries?

Tags: discussion

I don't think that this has a simple solution, but I think it would be nice if we could differentiate between questions about a language and questions about language libraries and programs written in that language.

For example, nearly any question about jQuery, Raphael, Angular, Knockout, Backbone, or Ember is going to be tagged with Javascript.  I tag my own questions thus.  Questions like: "How do I select the first row of a table with jQuery?" or "How can I restrict a value by regex in Knockout?"

I think that such questions are really in a separate category from questions about the language itself, such as questions about the syntax, computation, organization, etc.  Questions like: "Why is it a bad idea to use Javascript semi-colon insertion?" or "How are variables scoped in Javascript?"

Is there a way we could use the tag system or some other feature of SO to make this distinction?

Comment: The [tag:objc] tag excerpt provides this kind of guidance: "only [...] questions that are about Objective-C or depend on code in the language". Beyond that, it just requires vigilant editing.

Comment: Afraid that ship may have sailed a long long time ago...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tag with both, as you currently do.**

Tags serve to notify a given audience that they might be interested in a particular question. If you don't use the [Javascript] tag, you are missing a huge audience if they aren't following the library as well as the language. By additionally tagging [jQuery], it is obvious that they are asking about that library in particular (or at least they think they are).

If you, as a reader, don't want to see [jQuery] questions, you can always search for [Javascript] without [jQuery] questions.

You use the syntax described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

> [Javascript] - [jQuery]

Comment: Some questions are truly about the library/framework's features, and have no important relationship to the language. For my own favorite language, here's two recent examples: [How to create screen indicator in OS X application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26685894), [Result of Core Data query does not change when using a predicate to filter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26700066). The answers to either of these don't depend on the ObjC language at all -- they would be the same in essence if one were using any of the other language bindings for the Cocoa framework.

Comment: Does SO have a feature where you can exclude tags from your search?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon Yes, there was a few meta questions a while back on how to set up that search. I believe you have to modify the query string yourself, there is no way to do it through the UI. See my edit