# Creating a distinction between language specific questions that mention external libraries and those that don't

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I haven't done a research on this but the majority of the questions are about how to do this in this library and that in that library. Since there are thousands of libraries for each language out there and since the majority of users have to scroll through the questions over and over again that are about libraries they are ignorant of, how about this:

Imagine a new tag that says "native" or "internal" or similar, which means it doesn't relate to any external libraries but only the standard ones provided by the language. With some additional tweaks one could subscribe to a "C++ internal" tag, or something like that, and this way he would have the option to avoid the endless flow of questions about libraries he doesn't necessarily want to deal with. What do you think?

Comment: Is this need not already met by adding tags for libraries you aren't interested in to your ignored tag list?

Comment: Maintaining that list is not something I'd enjoy doing in my free time.

Comment: Do you want to go through all existing questions tagging those that *don't* use libraries with the no-libraries tags in your free time?

Comment: There is already a tag [tag:native], though it reates to native code as opposed to managed code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, actually I wouldn't want to do that either, not that what I proposed would require me to. Backwards compatibility is something that demolishes innovation, even if it's rather important most of the time.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd describe *"I don't even want to **read** questions mentioning things I don't know yet"* as *"innovation"*, but OK.

Comment: People's stupidity sometimes truly amazes me, you tell me about innovation when you are in the way of innovation right now, instead of trying to understand my idea you just pour negativity on it. You don't see the educational purpose at all. Being able the learn a language from the inside out is the wisest method to act by sometimes or for some. This should be an option, to subscribe to channels that only focus on the core part of the language. If you disagree with the concept then critique the concept first then the possible implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a few discussions about this: [Languages vs libraries](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302863/languages-vs-libraries), [How can we differentiate questions about a language from language libraries?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276056/how-can-we-differentiate-questions-about-a-language-from-language-libraries), and a couple of others I can't track down. The upshot seems to be:

1. Most people feel that it's on the individual user to figure out how to avoid questions they don't like.
2. Those who are in favor of coming up with community driven solution to this don't agree with how that should work.

So it's probably not going to happen until those two things aren't true.

Comment: But how does someone who wishes to learn more about standard c++ exclusively (not me, an arbitrary individual), manages to keep out non-standard c++ question from his subscription to the `c++` tag?

Comment: @AndrewVegvari - I don't know but the consensus seems to be that that's a personal problem, not a SO/community/site problem.

Comment: A useful technique to note is that you can use a wildcard tag search for the library / framework you want to ignore. Then just copy the resulting tag expansions over to your ignored tags list. You have to remove the brackets, but that can be easily accomplished with RegEx(p). This is what I've done in the past when I find that my recommended tab is full of questions I don't care about. cc@AndrewVegvari

Answer (score 0):

A direct reason to say *no* might be that it's a meta tag. From the [help page on tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging):

> Do not use [meta-tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) in questions. Here are some tips to help you
> determine whether a tag is a meta-tag:
>
> - **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as
>   the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like `[beginner]`, `[subjective]`,
>   and `[best-practices]`, are not helpful by themselves – they do not
>   communicate anything about the content of the question.
> - **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.** For example, the meaning of the tag
>   `[subjective]` is, itself, subjective; the same is true for tags like
>   `[best-practices]` and `[beginner]`. Best practices to whom? Beginner by
>   what criteria? Use only tags that have a broadly accepted, objective
>   definition.

It certainly fits the first bullet point, but that only makes it "probably" a meta-tag. I might be wrong here.

Comment: It probably also fits the second. How *standard* must it be to be acceptable?

Comment: You're probably right, I'm just holding off on that because the suggestion doesn't specify an exact name. (Just two that mean something else already.)