# Remove language tag when not directly about that language?

Tags: discussion, tags

You could probably really say this question is really about how bad search is on Stack Overflow.

The issue in particular though is that someone posts a question about a library. They tag the question with the language the libraries uses which AFAIK is or used to be the recommended way on SO as adding the language tag tells SO how to format your code blocks if they aren't manually tagged.

The problem is with the language tag it leads SO to link the question to completely unrelated topics.

As an example here is a question:

[image: Screenshot of example question]

Notice the "related" list has pretty much nothing to do whatsoever with the actual question. The only connection whatsoever seems to be the JavaScript tag which I why I'm asking...

Would it be better if language tags were only used if the question is really a question about language usage itself and otherwise the language tag should be removed?

A [related discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276056/how-can-we-differentiate-questions-about-a-language-from-language-libraries) says you should put the language tag though as pointed out above this is having bad repercussions as it's not helping lead to answers nor is it helping with getting answers.

[This Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250876/language-tags-on-library-questions) also effectively says "always put the language tag" but again, it's not having its intended effect AFAIK.

Comment: I suspect that, except perhaps for very popular libraries, this would in fact severely curtail the pool of answerers for library questions.

Comment: In reality it is very context-sensitive, what applies for one tag does not necessarily have to apply for another tag. So I wouldn't try to make a hard rule or even a guideline out of this, always reason about it from case to case and when in doubt just leave the tag.

Comment: side question... who threw up on your browser? And did they eat a box of fruity pebbles beforehand?

Comment: If you're talking about the bright colored theme, I have 5 user profiles for various things (work, personal, etc...) and the bright colors help me know which profile I'm using.

Answer (score 7):

I see several problems when we completely ban language tags from library questions:

- Small libraries will loose a lot of visibility. Although it might work out for [three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/three.js), I highly doubt that smaller libraries have a large enough community.
- Libraries are not necessarily tied to a specific programming language. [opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl), for example, contains questions from C++, C#, Java, Python and many more languages. Without knowing which language is involved it is hard to judge for contributors to decide whether they are able to answer the question. It could also make problems with searching these questions because if you have a problem with OpenGL in Java, then a question about OpenGL in C++ might not help.

Note, that I'm not against removing language tags in specific cases, for example, removing javascript from three.js questions. But I don't think we should make a general rule for it.

Comment: Angular, React and by the looks of it even three.js indeed I would consider to remove the javascript tag; those tags in themselves already represent a wide enough net, no need to widen the net further to a massive group of people who are in no way guaranteed to be interested in questions about these topics or will be very tempted to "help" with answers in the form of "Don't know X, but here's how you do it with Y". You know Y is JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Really no...

The language tag is used to say "I want answer in this language". For your particular case of JavaScript + tree.js - would answers in CoffeScript, ScriptSharp, TypeScript and all other languages that cross-compile to JavaScript be as useful to OP as JavaScript?